# Laravel retrive failed job id to attach to request for resubmission

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I have server build requests that trigger dispatch jobs. The requests are view-able in a table where you can see the status of the job for each server. When the job fails I want a resubmit button in a column that can resubmit that failed job by ID. The issue I'm having is retrieving the failed job ID from the failed_jobs table for given job. I can get the jobID just not sure how to get the failed jobID. I have the `public function failed($exceiption)` but not sure how to retrieve the id here. Once I have it I can complete the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Job ID from the [Job Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#job-events) that are fired during the queue process.

In you app service provider's boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->exception
    });
}
```

There you can get the ID property from `$event->job`.

Comment: The only thing I get from Queue:failing is $event->connectionName which spits out **database** everything else doesn't log anything.

Comment: To clarify this answer: $event->job->getJobId() will return the Job id in the above context. Now, that will be the id of the Job - NOT of the failed job.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there is no reliable way to get the id of the failed job, which is frustrating.

#### However, you can accomplish the same by embedding whatever data you are trying to relate to the failed job within the failed job itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854705/1615077